# optimize string search on black-box function

Tags: algorithms, optimization, strings

Given a lower-bound predicate function which returns `true` if an input is greater than or equal to a constant string, what is the optimal way to search for the constant? The strings should be lexicographical compared.

For example, given a handle to the following function, but not knowing the specific constant used:

```
fn lower_bound(s: &[u8]) -> bool {
    s >= &[10, 20, 30]
}
```

What is the optimal algorithm for determining the enclosed value of `&[10, 20, 30]`?  A maximum length for the value can be assumed if that makes it more tractable.

Answer (score 2):

The most optimal algorithm would be to perform a binary search for each character sequentially (bin-search for 1st char, bin-search for 2nd char, ...etc).